# Show dialogfragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to display a dialogfragment which implements the datepickerdialog inside a fragment!
I have a button whose listener displays the datepickerdialog.
The button is defined in fragment layout as:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelectDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
```

The code of the fragment class is the following(my problem is in showDatePickerDialog function):

```
public  class SchedulerChooserFragment extends Fragment {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    TextView dateText;   
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); 
        rootView = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler_chooser, container,false);

        return rootView;
    }



    // display current date
    public void showCurrentDateOnView() {

        dateText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.textDate);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        System.out.println("year" + year);
        // set current date into textview
        dateText.setText(month + 1 +"-"+day+"-"+year);

        // set current date into datepicker


    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(dateText);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");            
    }

}
```

However, the getSupportFragmentManager does not exist inside a fragment.
I have tried getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager but the app crashes.
Also, I have tried getChildFragmentManager, and the app crashes too.

The datePickerFragment class is the folllowing:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    TextView txtDate;


     public DatePickerFragment(TextView txtDate) {
        super();
        this.txtDate = txtDate;
    }

    @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            /*txtDate.setText(year+" " +month +" "+ date);*/
        }



}
```

I am new to android! Sorry, if my issue is obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
The Log output threw a java.lang.IllegalStateException: about not finding the showDatePickerDialog which was defined as android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
 for a button.

But, it is not possible to define onclick methods like this inside fragments.
So i changed the SchedulerChooserFragment to :

```
public  class SchedulerChooserFragment extends Fragment   implements OnClickListener{

        View rootView;
        TextView textDisplayDate;
        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler_chooser, container,false);
            showCurrentDateOnView();
            Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            return rootView;
        }

     // display current date
            public void showCurrentDateOnView() {

                textDisplayDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);


                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // set current date into textview
                textDisplayDate.setText(year+" "+month+" "+day);


            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.buttonSelectDate:

                     DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(textDisplayDate);
                    newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                    break;
                }

            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SchedulerChooserFragment imports for fragment and FragmentManager must both be from android.support.v4.app

So,

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I have the imports as you said, and the application still crashes!!!
Even if i  use the getChildFragmentManager

        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(dateText);
        newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");  

Is it feasible to show a dialogFragment under a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(dateText);
```

dateText is a TextView - you can't set a TextView to the Dialog ;)

edit: show your error log ;)

Comment: I have add the DatePickerFragment class to my initial post.
I have a constructor DatePickerFragment(TextView textDate). Thus,
i guess new DatePIckerFragment(dateText) is not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
```

Dialog Fragment inside Fragment

Use this

import `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`

inplace of

```
android.app.DialogFragment;
```